# AVR-GCC support for ATXMega16a4u

Tags: linux, microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc, atmel

I have a ATXMega16a4u mcu of Atmel and try to compile code with avr-gcc 4.7.2 (Fedora 4.7.2-1.fc17). I got this error:

> Unrecognized argument in option '-mmcu=atxmega16a4u'

So I tried to compile code with -mmcu=atxmega16a4 (without 'u' in the end). And get some 'undeclared' errors:

> error: 'ADC_CH_GAIN_DIV2_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)

Is my microcontroller not supported yet by avr-gcc? Is there any possibility to make it work on Fedora, avoiding using avr studio (and windows)?

Thanks
Long

Answer (score 2):

The ATxmega16A4U is [not supported by AVR-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/index.html). Your undefined symbol there is an error tossed by the C compiler. A cursory reading of Atmel's website shows that the two microcontrollers, ATxmega16A4U and the ATxmega16A4, are different devices, with the most prominent difference being the USB interface present in the former. As a consequence, some of the register descriptions found on the include files given by `avr/io.h` will not be readily avaiable for the ATxmega16A4U. The solution to this problem is to create a new header file containing the necessary definitions for this microcontroller. This takes care of the libc side. For the compiler/linker side, you may have to patch gcc to take the proper `-mmcu` option and define the symbols expected by `avr/io.h` in general. A linker script may be necessary as well, though a cursory read of Atmel's website suggests that the memory layout for both microcontrollers to be the same, so this last step may not be necessary.